# How to get the camera matrix used for calibrating the camera

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using acA4112-30uc - Basler ace camera. I'm trying to get rid of distortion, but in order to do that, I have to get the "mtx" parameter, which, I have no idea how to get.

Answer (score 1):

theory of camera calibration with OPENCV is here : [OPENCV_DOC](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d94/tutorial_camera_calibration.html)

First you need to fix camera. then print chessboard [chessboardtoprint](https://gofile.io/?c=zMwu7m)

**PART A: take image and perform calculations**

after print, put it on a book. then take some images by camera using this code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

objp = np.zeros((6 * 7, 3), np.float32)
objp[ : , : 2] = np.mgrid[0 : 7, 0 : 6].T.reshape(-1, 2)
objpoints = []
imgpoints = []

criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
(w, h) = (int(cam.get(4)), int(cam.get(3)))

while(True):
    _ , frame = cam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7, 6), None)

    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)
        corners = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners)

        cv2.drawChessboardCorners(frame, (7, 6), corners, ret)
        cv2.imshow('Find Chessboard', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.imshow('Find Chessboard', frame)
    print "Number of chess boards find:", len(imgpoints)        
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

ret, oldMtx, coef, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints,
                                                      gray.shape[: : -1], None, None)
newMtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(oldMtx, coef, (w, h), 1, (w, h))

print "Original Camera Matrix:\n", oldMtx
print "Optimal Camera Matrix:\n", newMtx

np.save("Original camera matrix", oldMtx)
np.save("Distortion coefficients", coef)
np.save("Optimal camera matrix", newMtx)

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

in this code you open camera and put printed chessboard in many positions to code detect chessboard for matrices calculations. Each time code detect chessboard show image and print number of detected images. after some images you can press Esc to finish calculation.

**PART B: Use matrices to correct camera output**

you can use this code for test:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

oldMtx = np.load("Original camera matrix.npy")
coef = np.load("Distortion coefficients.npy")
newMtx = np.load("Optimal camera matrix.npy")

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
(w, h) = (int(cam.get(4)), int(cam.get(3)))

while(True):
    _ , frame = cam.read()

    undis = cv2.undistort(frame, oldMtx, coef, newMtx)

    cv2.imshow("Original vs Undistortion", np.hstack([frame, undis]))
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

good luck!